# How can I write an integral with a symbol of cross (“x”) over the integral?

Tags: integral

The integral that I want to write is the integral cross, I want to put an “x” on the integral...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How big should the "x" be? Like `\times`? Or bigger, or smaller?

Comment: I want to write the integral like https://services.math.duke.edu/~dasgupta/papers/shintani.pdf in pag.8

Answer (score 11):

If you use lualatex/xelatex, you can load some font that has the slot `u+02A18`, which can be accessed by `\intx`. The New Computer Modern font has it (I use the nice slightly bolder version below).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{NewCM10-Book.otf}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}

\begin{document}
\[\intx_G f(x)\, d\mu(x)\]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Integral with an x over it.]

Answer (score 8):

Shamelessly borrowing (stealing?) some code from the posting [The Principal Value Integral symbol](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-prinvalint) on the TeX-FAQ site, here's a suggestion for a directive called `\intmult` -- short for "multiplicative integral".

[image]

IMNSHO, I think that this version of the multiplicative integral symbol actually looks a lot better than the one in the paper by Dasgupta. (In the Dasgupta paper, the intersection of the `\times` symbol does *not* lie on top of the integral symbol.)

```
\documentclass{article}

% The following code is copied from https://texfaq.org/FAQ-prinvalint
\def\Xint#1{\mathchoice
   {\XXint\displaystyle\textstyle{#1}}%
   {\XXint\textstyle\scriptstyle{#1}}%
   {\XXint\scriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}%
   {\XXint\scriptscriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}%
   \!\int}
\def\XXint#1#2#3{{\setbox0=\hbox{$#1{#2#3}{\int}$}
     \vcenter{\hbox{$#2#3$}}\kern-.5\wd0}}
\def\intmult{\Xint\times}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\intmult_0^1 \quad \textstyle\intmult_0^1$ \qquad vs.\qquad
$\displaystyle\int_0^1 \quad \textstyle\int_0^1$
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, thank you!

Comment: I think this looks better than what they do in the linked paper. Their integrals on page 8 and page 11 differ.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a possibility to use `stix` font. I remember that stix font change all the math-font of the whole tex document. Alternatively you can declare only the symbol of the integral, but I think that this is not a good approach.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[\intx_C f(z)dz\]
$\intx_C f(z)dz$
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

*Alternatively you can use a primitive simple syntax using `\kern`*.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\int_D\kern-1.2em\scriptstyle \times\kern.5em f(z)dz$
\[\int_D\kern-1.1em\scriptstyle \times\kern.5em f(z)dz\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I prefered to not use the “stick” package because it changes the style of all my paper, but I will take for the next works!

Comment: @FedericoRomagnani Hi Federico and thank you very much for your advice. Tanti saluti dalla Sicilia orientale.